# Limitations of Local Kernel Mode Debugging in Windbg?

Tags: windbg

Are there some limitations to the Local Kernel Mode Debugging option in Windbg?

I am running Win XP SP3 inside a VM using VMWare Workstation. The Host operating system is: Windows 7 SP1

I want to perform Kernel Debugging using Windbg inside the VM.

However, few commands are not working. For instance,

```
lkd> !process -0 0

PROCESS 82cd38b0  SessionId: 0  Cid: 0cd4    Peb: 7ffd6000  ParentCid: 0638
    DirBase: 0e740300  ObjectTable: e2474a10  HandleCount:  43.
    Image: notepad.exe

lkd> .process /i 82cd38b0
              ^ Operation not supported by current debuggee error in '.process /i 82cd38b0'
    Image: notepad.exe

lkd> !lmu
No export lmu found
```

So, my guess is that these are limitations of the local kernel mode debugging option of windbg.

Answer (score 2):

Local kernel mode debugging is very limited, you can't even set a breakpoint. More about limitations [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff553382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Set up a remote kernel debug via COM port on the guest system with redirection to a pipe on the host system. Then you can execute all debugging commands.

Comment: Thank you and yes I have been trying to get that set up. But I believe the response speed is a concern while connecting through a virtual serial port.

Comment: Virtual serial port works much faster than the real one. For superspeed you can try VirtualKD: http://virtualkd.sysprogs.org/