# Make windbg or kd attached to local kernel behave like system wide strace

Tags: windows, debugging, system-calls, windb, livekd

I am running Windows 7 on which I want to do kernel debugging and I do not want to mess with boot loader. So I've downloaded LiveKd as suggested [here](https://gds89.wordpress.com/2010/05/19/windows-7-x64-local-and-live-kernel-debugging/) and make it run and seems it is working. If I understand correct it is some kind of read only debugging. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738579/limitations-of-local-kernel-mode-debugging-in-windbg) is mentioned that it is very limited and even breakpoint cannot be used. I would like to ask if is possible in this mode to periodically dump all the instructions that are being executed or basically all events which are happening on current OS? I would like to have some system wide strace (Linux users know) and to do some statistical analysis on this. I suppose it depends on more factors like installed debug symbols to begin able resolve addresses etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if debugger is the best tool you can use for tracing live system calls. As you've mentioned LiveKd session is quite limited and you are not allowed to place breakpoints in it (otherwise you would hang your own system). However, you still can create memory dumps using the `.dump` command (check windbg help: `.hh .dump`). Keep in mind though that getting a full dump (`/f`) of a running system might take a lot of time.

Moving back to the subject of your question, by using the "dump approach" you will miss many system calls as you will have only snapshots of a system at given points in time. So if you are looking for something similar to Linux `strace` I would recommend checking those tools:

- [Process Monitor (procmon)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) - it's a tool which will show you all I/O requests in the system, as well as operations performed on the registry or process activity events
- [Windows Performance Toolkit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh162945.aspx) - it contains tools for collecting (WPR) and analysing (WPA) system and application tracing events. It might be a lot of events and it's really important to filter them accordingly to your needs. ETW (Event Tracing for Windows) is a huge subject and you probably will need to read some tutorials or books before you will be able to use it effectively (but it's really worth it!).
- [API Monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor) - it's one of many (I consider it as one of the best) tracing applications - this tool will allow you to trace method calls in any of the running processes. It has a nice interface and even allows you to place breakpoints on methods you'd like to intercept.

There are many other tools which might be used for tracing on Windows, but I would start with the ones I listed above. You may also check a great book on this subject: [Inside Windows Debugging](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735662789). Good luck! :)

Comment: Hello lowleveldesign, thank you for reply and for mentioned tools. About WPT I've read before but never tried probably because the name which resembles that is decided to performance tracking issues. Does those utilities supports some kind of batch usage? Goal is to obtain data of current system not to interact with it. You're right memory dumps is not what I want for mentioned reasons. Even if windbg is limited in LiveKd session it AFAIK acts like observer. I suppose it should have knowledge about actual instruction being executed. I'm now talking about assembly instructions not syscalls. THX

Comment: @WakanTanka you may call wpr from command line to start/stop trace collection. There is also another tool: xperf which has even better console suppport. And yes, while live debugging you may examine stack traces of the running threads.

Comment: Hello, lowleveldesign: wpr is not windbg's command or is it? The xperf seems ot be part of WPT? I'm wondering if windbg does not have such command just for curiosity. I've spend a lot of time to make it run (although it was as remote kernel debugger) so I would like to give a try in near future alongside with mentioned utilities.